# Recovery of deleted data from a modern disk

Tags: forensics, windows-10, data-recovery

I have the opposite problem of this question's OP: [What can be recovered? Securely deleted files](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191562/what-can-be-recovered-securely-deleted-files)

I deleted some files in September 2017 and need to have them back. I actually gave up on this, but then came about the question mentioned above.
As I understand, it is extremely difficult to actually make data unrecoverable.

I'm using windows-10. And the Disk is not an SSD.

So what tools, procedures or methods are available to recover my data?
I'm a software developer for low level embedded devices, so I can hack together some stuff if anyone can give me a direction.
Also I know the file types and approximate size of the data.

I've tried PhotoRec to recover it. And it turned up a LOT of things, but nothing of the data I looked for.

(I lost the data by shift-delete'ing it after encrypting with winrar (aes256) and forgetting the security-level-paranoid password)

The data might also have been partly overwritten

Comment: How often was the HDD used since the deletion of the data you want to recover? How large are the file(s) you want to recover (larger files -> lower chance for data recovery because of fragmentation)? What data type (e.g. JPEG, DOC; ...) are the file(s) you want to recover?

Comment: If you have used this drive in the meantime, there's a high chance you've overwritten those files and nothing is salvageable.  You still could give R-Studio Undelete a try: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000